# OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (i < src.channels()) in cvSplit

Tags: c++, opencv

i am running a basic application using openCV for C++.  I am attempting to split the image into rgb components using `cvSplit()` as below:

```
CvMat* mat;

//initialize mat

CvMat* b = cvCreateMat(mat->rows, mat->cols, CV_8UC1);
CvMat* g = cvCreateMat(mat->rows, mat->cols, CV_8UC1);
CvMat* r = cvCreateMat(mat->rows, mat->cols, CV_8UC1);
cvSplit(mat, b, g, r, NULL );
```

It builds just fine, but when I attempt to run it, I get the following error:

```
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (i < src.channels()) in cvSplit, file /home/username/Downloads/OpenCV-2.4.0/modules/core/src/convert.cpp, line 1196
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception'
```

What does this error mean, and how can I solve the problem?

Comment: How are you initializing `mat`? The error indicates there's a problem with the number of color channels in the source (`mat` in your case)

Comment: I'm converting from an IplImage:  `CvMat tmp;
  CvMat* mat = cvGetMat(img, &tmp, 0, 0);`
the IplImage is retrieve from elsewhere.  I am not in control of it

Comment: I'm not that familiar with OpenCV, but can `cvGetMat(img, &tmp, 0, 0);` cause an issue with the resulting matrix because your `tmp` is statically allocated? What if you try to allocate it dynamically with the appropriate rows and columns?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The IplImage you are using to create the Mat should be in color. You need three channels to be able to use `cvSplit`. You can check this with `IplImage->nChannels` in your debugger.

Comment: indeed. the IplImage was greyscale.